# The problem with getting the top container component. Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I click on a tree record, I try to set the values ​​of this record and set these values ​​in the form.

In the eventcler `itemclick: this.showDataFields` function is triggered:

```
....

showDataFields: function(view, record, item, index, event) {
        //got a form with fields
        var panel = view.up('maintab');
       console.log(panel)

        //var formfield   = panel.down('actionform');
        //assign values from selected record to form fields
        //formfield.loadRecord(record);

    },

..........
```

In this function, `view.up ('maintab')` is underfined.

The `maintab` is `Ext.tab.Panel` which houses the tree.

Why can not get the topmost container and how to do it correctly?

Made an example in [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nno)

thank

Comment: You can't declare an xtype inline while creating a component instance. New xtypes are supposed to go on class definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have provided a better example, therefore within the limitations that were proposed.

The answer I got was this were the changes in the ActionFormTree class that got the code below:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.ActionFormTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.actionformtree',
    xtype: 'actionform',//mainform,
    initComponent: function(){
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me,{
            items: [{
                xtype: 'form',
                border: false,
                anchor: '100%',
                height: 100,
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'middle',
                    pack: 'center'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'text',
                    fieldLabel: 'Наименование',
                    itemId: 'name_field',
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'code',
                    fieldLabel: 'Код',
                    itemId: 'code_field',
                }]
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Save Changes',
                scope: me,
                handler: function (button) {
                    //Эта панель со значениями полей
                    form   = me.down('form');

                    var mainpanel = me.up('#maincontainer');
                    var treeform   = mainpanel.down('usertree');
                    var sel = treeform.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                    store = treeform.getStore();

                    console.log(treeform)
                    store.suspendAutoSync()
                    var child = sel.set({
                        text: 'Измененное',
                        leaf: true
                    });

                    sel.expand()
                    store.resumeAutoSync();

                    //var currRecord = form.getRecord();

                    //if (currRecord) {
                    //    form.updateRecord();
                    //   form.reset();
                    //}
                }
            }]            
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

**So, in this example, for it to work, you will need to have a node selected to work.**

Hope it helps and finalize your question.

[Sample to your code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nno)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `view.up('treepanel').nextSibling().getForm().setValues(record.data)` in your `showDataFields` function to set these values ​​in the form.